# Simple tool for web server benchmarking?

Tags: performance, load, webserver

I want to make some simple load tests for a web application.

I remember one of the tools I have seen in a stage and I liked a lot was [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), but it is intended for developing use cases for testing user interface of  web application.

My needs are simpler, simulate concurrent users. I have seen Apache Benchmark 'ab' but one thing I would like to do is **simulate a scenario where we begin with 5 users and make increments of 10, 15 ... until we reach 50 users** (increments each 10 seconds, by example).

Do you recommend a simple tool for this use case?

Regards

Comment: [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) - check out *ramp up period*

Answer (score 3):

I have chosen **[JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org)**. It is not as simple as ab from Apache or httperf, but it isn't a complicated tool.

In the JMeter docs we can see a [simple tutorial for doing web load tests](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html). For the scenario for incrementing user number there is the configuration **Ramp-Up Period** which tells JMeter how long to delay between starting each user.

[image: Test thread configuration]

Answer (score 2):

you may like `curl-loader` which supports customed number of users per-second and test different URLs.

there's another tool named `siege`, which is quite similar to `ab`(apache benchmark), have a try.